# Use full group record within title in dc-js geoChoropleth chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a group for which elements after reduction look like this pseudocode :

```js
{
  key:"somevalue",
  value: {
    sum: the_total,
    names:{
     a: a_number,
     b: b_number,
     c:c_number
    }
  }
}
```

In my dc-js geoChoropleth graph the `valueAccessor` is `(d) => d.value.sum`

In my `title`, I would like to use the `names` component of my reduction. But when I use `.title((d) => {...})`, I can onjly access the key and the value resulting from the `valueAccessor` function instead of the original record.

Is that meant to be ?

Comment: Which chart? I would not expect to see the original data record, but sure, the reduced group key/value record should be available.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it. Datatable.

Comment: I don't understand - does `dc.dataTable` use `.title()`? In other charts that is used for displaying the SVG tooltip (`title` tag), but the data table is HTML.

Comment: Oops brain fart. It's on the geochloropeth one sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a peculiarity of the geoChoropleth chart.

Most charts bind the group data directly to chart elements, but since the geoChoropleth chart has two sources of data, the map and the group, it [binds the map data and hides the group data](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1268).

Here is the direct culprit:

```
_renderTitles (regionG, layerIndex, data) {
    if (this.renderTitle()) {
        regionG.selectAll('title').text(d => {
            const key = this._getKey(layerIndex, d);
            const value = data[key];
            return this.title()({key: key, value: value});
        });
    }
}
```

It is creating key/value objects itself, and the value, as you deduced, comes from the `valueAccessor`:

```
_generateLayeredData () {
    const data = {};
    const groupAll = this.data();
    for (let i = 0; i < groupAll.length; ++i) {
        data[this.keyAccessor()(groupAll[i])] = this.valueAccessor()(groupAll[i]);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Sorry this is not a complete answer, but I would suggest adding a `pretransition` handler that replaces the titles, or alternately, using the key passed to the title accessor to lookup the data you need.

As I noted in the issue linked above, I think this is a pretty serious design bug.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am going to use a custom d3-tip to achieve what I need. It's more flexible anyway, this is what I usually do for all my dc graphs.

Comment: Sure, d3-tip is great! Thanks for following up.